# Trigger(Touch) not working anymore on Android Unity3D VR App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

My Cardboard-like `VR-Viewer` has a button that works by touching the screen. I created an app in `Unity3D` and this trigger mechanic first worked like a charm. Now all of a sudden, I think I only added an explosion particle effect, the touch function stopped working completely. I have tried things like removing the explosion from my scene again, but nothing seems to work. Another curious thing is, that I can't close the app in a normal way anymore (normally in VR Apps you have an X-Button in the top left of your screen, but clicking it doesn't do anything anymore too (It used to work!)). App still runs, doesn't crash, but no interaction is possible. I looked at the debug logs via adb - no errors there... App works like it used to when I start it inside the `Unity Editor`. 
Did someone encounter a similar error or may have an idea about what the problem is? I'm using `Unity Daydream Preview 5.4.2f2`.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention I was using `GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered` to check if the screen was touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all having the same problem, I worked around it by also checking if a touch just happened. In my `Player : Monobehaviour` I used:

```
void Update()
{
    if (GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered || 
        Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        //Do stuff.
    }
}
```